# How to select iOS supported platforms

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I've built my second app for the iPad and submitted it for review; iTunes connect complained that Xcode suggested support for all the iPhone range from iPhone 3 upwards.
I developed the app for the iPad but configured it for the iPhone 6 and plus due to the increase in available area. Is there a way I can keep support for iPad and iPhone 6 or greater only?

Comment: No, if you support iPhone you will need to support  3.5", 4", 4.7" and 5" Since those are the size available. You do not need to support the iPhone 3 (this is not even possible since apple dropped support for ARMv6)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So Apple provide the additional real estate in the iPhone 6 but don't allow you as a developer to take advantage of it. A bit crazy! Thanks again!

Comment: They allow you top take full advantage of it, but then you will need to provide other iPhone's with an experience as well. You can (with size classes) device a different experience for the user on a iPhone 6+ then on the other device. For the iPhones what 3.5" and 4" the experience is almost the same. The iPhone 6 just has a little more with but the 6+ is really different.